# page view is not returning,,,while returning only simple value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a problem using Laravel Framework. I am trying to build a layout, but no mater how much I've tried I am getting the same error on my browser :

```
View [layouts.adminLayout.admin_design] not found. (View: 
E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\ecom2\resources\views\admin\dashboard.blade.php)
```

m following this tutorial

```
     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzYBu0iez3s
```

here is code of admin_design.blade.php

```
  @include('layouts.adminLayout.admin_header')
  @include('layouts.adminLayout.admin_sidebar')   
  @yield('content')
  @include('layouts.adminLayout.admin_footer')
```

and this is in dashboard.blade.php

```
  @extends('layouts.adminLayout.admin_design')
  @section('content')
```

this is the code of its controller

```
public function dashboard(){

return view('admin.dashboard');
}
```

if i write echo "test"; die;

then it shows die but is not showing the desired page... is there any solution for this prblm

Comment: Within your `resources/views/` folder do you have another folder called `admin` and then within that folder you have `dashboard.blade.php`?

Comment: yes, always have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your usage this should be your structure:

```
resources
  views
    admin
        dashboard.blade.php
    layouts
        adminLayout
            admin_header.blade.php
            admin_sidebar.blade.php
            admin_footer.blade.php
            admin_design.blade.php
```

if you have the `layouts` folder within your `admin` folder then you should use `admin.layouts.adminLayout.VIEW_NAME`

Comment: my structure us same as u mentioned above but still showing error @nakov

Comment: The error that is displayed is because a view with name `admin_design` cannot be found on that path. So you can try extending another view in order to check if there is something with the view. Or if you cache the views try running `php artisan view:clear` if that helps.

Comment: tried php artisan view:clear but still same result,,,i also cleared the history but still same issue,,,,is there any alternate path to find admin_design

Comment: Can you try to make that file completely empty, so remove all the content and check if you still have the error. If the error still appears I doubt that your structure is the same, so it will help if you share a screenshot of it.

Comment: when i empty the file completely then it showed me a blank page,,,, its also showing the echo "test"; die; on the dashboard.blade.php,,,,,,and the error showed by this when i try to open dashboard is:    https://imageshack.com/i/pmmmYSySp

Comment: Can you please give me a screenshot of your resources folder?

Comment: so I see you have an error in spelling. You have the views `balde` it should be `blade.php`

Comment: thnx a lot @nakov